# Compiling C as C++ linker error (lua and oolua)

Tags: c++, c, lua, oolua

I am having trouble with a piece of C code that is compiled as C++ producing a linker error from a 3rd package.

The setup is I have lua, oolua, and my program which utilizes the two. This project was moved from luabind due to its horrid build process. My code occasionally will throw an exception (which is expected) when constructing an object, and oolua does not handle this error.

From the reading I've done compiling lua as C++ should alleviate this problem and cause the program to not just quit, but the problem is oolua doesn't like lua being C++ for some reason and I cannot find references to why this could be.

tl;dr: If C code is compiled as C++ what problems could occur with linking assuming it compiles correctly?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what problems you are having? There is a whole universe of difficulties you might encounter.

Comment: Are the C declarations wrapped in `extern "C"`?

Comment: @ildjarn The code does compile correctly when compiled as C but not as C++. There are no new C declarations in oolua, or are you talking about lua?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Its a linker error coming from oolua and upon closer inspection, wherever a C function from lua is referred to. Also if it helps lua is being statically linked.

Comment: @KGardevoir : That doesn't really answer the question – are the publicly visible type/function declarations for lua wrapped in `extern "C"` or aren't they?

Comment: @ildjarn Its a combination of both, I have some plain C functions that I am exporting, and some C++ that oolua binds for me. Unless you are asking about the API which there is a header (which I am not using) that does wrap them in an `extern "C"` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Lua is compiled as C++ it actually uses C++ name mangling and the normal headers should be used by C++. Don't be confused by the `lua.hpp` header. That should only be used for C++ when Lua is compiled as C. As a result when you compile Lua as C++ you should *not* use `extern "C"`. Unfortunately OOLua does use `extern "C"` [here](http://code.google.com/p/oolua/source/browse/trunk/include/lua_includes.h). You could try modifying the header in OOLua to not use `extern "C"` and then recompile OOLua or file a bug with them to fix it properly.

Unfortunately not many people seem to be aware of the pitfalls of using Lua with C++ so many projects assume Lua is compiled as C as normal.

Long explanation:

When Lua is compiled as C there are no extern statements and therefore all functions get the default (`extern "C"`). When C files use Lua they use the normal header files which again contain no extern statements so the compiler presumes everything to be `extern "C"` and it all matches the library. If you use Lua from C++ you use `lua.hpp` which contains the `extern "C"` block so your compiler knows that Lua is `extern "C"`.

When Lua is compiled as C++ there are no extern statements so the compiler assumes all functions in Lua are `extern "C++"`. You can no longer use Lua directly from C. If you use Lua from C++ with the `lua.hpp` then it sees the `extern "C"` block, assumes Lua functions are `extern "C"` and fails at link time because of the wrong mangling. If you use the normal headers directly from C++ then there are no extern statements so `extern "C++"` is assumed. This matches the library and all is OK.

What OOLua does is it includes the normal headers but has it's own `extern "C"` around it so the compiler uses `extern "C"` linkage for all Lua functions when they are in fact using C++ linkage, the mangling is wrong and you get lots of linker errors about missing symbols.

Comment: That's along the lines of what I though was going on, but I'm no C++ guru so I wasn't sure.